# Bootstrap modal inside modal is not fading the outer modal on initiation of inner modal

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am initiating one modal on one button click and inside that modal, I am triggering one more modal. However, when the second modal pops up I want the outer modal to fade or reduce its opacity. When I try to apply opacity with jquery and CSS, that opacity is applied to the inner modal as well. Is there a solution to this problem?

Below are my modals:

[image]

these are the image after applying css to outer modal opacity: 0.5
[image]

Comment: Try this
https://www.codeply.com/go/NiFzSCukVl/bootstrap-4-open-modal-from-another-modal

Comment: How are you applying the CSS, and what selectors are you applying them to?